# Как задать в .htaccess следующий редирект?

Tags: .htaccess

На сайте используется скрипт, который делает редиректы.
Создаётся ссылка http://mysite.com/r/dir/
Но если заходить на Создаётся ссылка http://mysite.com/r/dir,
то выдаётся ошибка 404.

Как в .htaccess прописать перенаправление с http://mysite.com/r/dir на http://mysite.com/r/dir/?

Comment: @Виктор Павлов, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Redirect r/dir/? http://mysite.com/r/dir
```

попробуйте) должно работать)

Comment: А можно ли прописать так, чтобы для любой директории r/... в конце дописывался слэш?